# Помогите с решением задачки

Tags: kotlin

Напишите программу, которая считывает три целых числа и выводит истину, если первое число находится между вторым и третьим (включительно). В противном случае вывести false.

Порядок сортировки двух последних аргументов может быть любым.

У меня получается такой код:

```
fun main() {
    val n1 = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val n2 = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val n3 = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val res = n1 >= n2 || n1 >= n3 || n3 >= n1
    println(res)
}
```

Но он не работает, если прописать значения 4, 3, 3

Comment: У вас хромает логическое решение задачи. Несколько условий, для того чтобы совместно выполняться, не могут быть объединены ИЛИ.

Answer (score 0):

```
val res = (n1 >= n2 && n1 <=n3) || (n1 <= n2 && n1 >= n3)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас разбираюсь)

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще вариант накину :)

```
val list = listOf(n1, n2, n3).sorted()
val res = list[1] == n1
```